# Can you get virus from previewing email attachments in Gmail?

Tags: email, web-browser, virus, gmail

If an email attachment such as .docx, jpeg, .xls, .pdf, etc. contains virus/malware and if I open it for preview (not opening it in Google Docs or downloading it and opening it) then can I get infected?

Answer (score 2):

You are actually opening the file in the browser. If the browser has a vulnerability that the file exploits, it is possible (though unlikely at this point) that you can get infected.

Comment: But is it too likely? No

Comment: @multithr3at3d oops, forgot to add a risk assessment there. Added.

Comment: Could you develop on why it's more unlikely in a browser? (for schroeder and @multithr3at3d)

Comment: @Pacopaco just that modern browsers getting infected from a file is going to be really difficult with sandboxing, etc.